# VueJs: use method from root element inside a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In a simple HTML page, I used the following vueJs code. I need to click on the button which will insert a checkbox and a text into the DOM.

My code follows:

```
<template id="add-item-template">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input  v-model="newItem" placeholder="add shopping list item" type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button @click="addItem" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Add!</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</template>

<div id="app" class="container">
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <add-item-component></add-item-component>
</div>
```

And the javascript part is :

```
<script>
    var data = {
        items: [
            {
                text: 'Bananas', 
                checked: true 
            }, 
            { 
                text: 'Apples', 
                checked: false 
            }
        ],
        title: 'My Shopping List'
    };

    Vue.component('add-item-component', {
        template: '#add-item-template',
        data: function () {
            return {
                newItem: ''
            }
        },
        props:['addItem']
    });

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: data,
        methods: {
            addItem: function () {
                var text;

                text = this.newItem.trim();
                if (text) {
                    this.items.push({
                        text: text,
                        checked: false
                    });
                    this.newItem = "";
                }
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

When I run the page, I find the following error message in console :

**[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined 
(found in component )**

I understand that `addItem` method is not defined in `add-item-template` template and so  although I used `addItem` as the prop, the click handler becomes undefined .

Now how  can I make the click handler work ??

Comment: You should handle `addItem` in a child component and `emit` the event to a parent

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov, can you show it in code ?

Comment: This could be made much more easily using v-for. You're doing it the hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click event in child component should be handled there and if you want to see the output in a parent component, you should `emit` an event to the parent. In parent component you can listen to that `emitted event` and handle that.

```js
var data = {
        items: [{ text: 'Bananas', checked: true }, { text: 'Apples', checked: false }],
        title: 'My Shopping List'
    };

Vue.component('add-item-component', {
    template: '#add-item-template',
    data: function () {
        return {
            newItem: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addItem() {
            const text = this.newItem.trim();
            if(text) {
              // we are emitting an event called "add" and data object {item: this.newItem}
              this.$emit('add', { text });
            }
        }
    }
});



new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data,
    methods: {
      // here we're handling `add` event from child component with destructured `data` object as a parameter
        addNewItem({text}) {
          data.items.push({
              text,
              checked: false
          });
          console.log(data)
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template id="add-item-template">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input  v-model="newItem" placeholder="add shopping list item" type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button @click="addItem" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Add!</button>
        </span>
        </div>
    </template>

<div id="app" class="container">
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <!-- here we are listening to the `add` event from the child component -->
    <add-item-component @add="addNewItem"></add-item-component>
    <div v-for="item in items"> {{ item.text }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: on clicking the button nothing is inserted into DOM

Comment: try to `console.log` the `item` in `addItem` of parent component

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed I've edited the answer and added a snippet so you can see the result in console.

Comment: By the way - you won't see anything in the DOM because you are not rendering `items`.

Comment: can you explain the `@add="addNewItem"` part ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed added comments. So `@add="addNewItem"` you can pretend as `@click="addNewItem"`

Comment: `addNewItem({item}) ` - why do you need the  curly braces ? where is it mentioned in the VueJS doc ? If `item` is an object here, how could you use `item.trim()` ?

Comment: `{item}` is destructured object `{item: someData}`. You can use it like `addNewItem(data)` and then instead of just `item` you should use `data.item`. `data = { item: this.newItem}` here is the passed object `this.$emit('add', {item: this.newItem});`. `item` is a key of object and the value is string.

Comment: And I'd suggest to `emit` trimmed string in order of  `immutability`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202561/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-daniyal-lukmanov).